# Is there a way to import several .txt files each becoming a separate dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-import, data-analysis

I have to work with 50+ .txt files each containing 2 columns and 631 rows where I have to do different operations to each (sometimes with each other) before doing data analysis. I was hoping there was a way to import each text file under a different dataframe in pandas instead of doing it individually. The code I've been using individually has been

```
df = pd.read_table(file_name, skiprows=1, index_col=0)
print(B)
```

I use `index_col=0` because the first row is the x-value. I use `skiprows=1` because I have to drop the title which is the first row (and file name in folder) of each .txt file. I was thinking maybe I could use glob package and importing all as a single data frame from the folder and then splitting it into different dataframes while keeping the first column as the name of each variable? Is there a feasible way to import all of these files at once under different dataframes from a folder and storing them under the first column name? All .txt files would be data frames of 2 col x 631 rows not including the first title row. All values in the columns are integers.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you store your file in a list named `filelist` (maybe using glob) you can use the following commands to read all files and store them on a dict.

```
dfdict = {f: pd.read_table(f,...) for f in filelist}
```

Then you can use each data frame with `dfdict["filename.txt"]`.